# Save the list of objects in environment with their name in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm facing a problem with R. I created a certain amount of dataframes after a series of subsettings of my big species table, according to sex, collection moment, family etc... I saved them as .csv files in my datasets/csv/ directory, and as you can imagine it gets quite confuse. So I thought to save those dataframes as a list which, after saving it as an r object, I can load as an unique object when I do analysis in a separate RMarkdown file. This will avoid mistakes in loading .csv files and me getting mad to search and load the right file in the /csv directory.

So. After deleting the useless objects I have a situation like this (with more dataframes).

```
my_list <- replicate(n = 10, expr = {data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))}, simplify = F)

names(my_list) <- c(paste("ciao", c(1:10)))
list2env(my_list ,.GlobalEnv)
```

Obviously the names of the dataframes are not just ciao 1, 2 etc... but are different from each other.
Now I would like to "come back" listing and naming each object with its name, something like

```
my_list2 <- list()
for (i in seq_along(ls())) {
  my_data[["The name of i-th object"]] <- list="i-th object"
}
```

And here I faced the problem. How can I call just the name of the i-th object using ls() basing on its position, which I get from seq_along?
I searched in the help page and in this and other websites, but I found nothing.

Thank you very much.
Simone.

Comment: Check out my answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames). I think it will be helpful in this situation and may provide a solution.

Comment: Why are you creating separate objects in the global environment? If they are in a list, leave them there. If you need them in an environment for some unknown reason, put them in a different environment that holds only these objects.

Comment: @Roland. In my original file there are separate objects. The one in the question was just an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some approaches:

**1) mget**

```
my_list2 <- mget(ls())
```

or possibly:

```
my_list2 <- mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv)
```

**2) eapply**

```
my_list2 <- eapply(.GlobalEnv, identity)
```

**3) get**  Incrementally expanding a list is not recommended from a performance  standpoint but if there are few objects it may not matter.  Could use `get(nm, .GlobalEnv)` isntead of just `get(nm)`:

```
nms <- ls()
my_list2 <- list()
for(nm in nms) my_list2[[nm]] <- get(nm)
```

**3a)** Similar to (3) but uses numeric indexes:

```
nms <- ls()
my_list2 <- list()
for(i in seq_along(nms)) my_list2[[nms[i]]] <- get(nms[i])
```

**3b)** Also uses get but without the `for` loop:

```
Map(get, ls())
```

**3c)** To specify the environment explicitly:

```
sapply(ls(), get, .GlobalEnv, simplify = FALSE)
```

**Note**:  Note that if they come from files you could consider reading them directly into a list using `read.table` or `read.csv`:

```
sapply(list.files(), read.csv, simplify = FALSE)
```